# PHP: currency data not displaying right

Tags: php

I am trying to display ebay deals rss into my wordpress site, I am using wordpress built functions to achieve this:

```
  $desc = $item->get_description();  // to get the feed item description
  setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
  echo utf8_encode(money_format('%n', $desc));
```

In when I get $235.99 it is being displayed as .99 or 5.99 used escape characters but with not use.... not sure what is wrong in this.

Comment: You need to remove the `$` from `$desc`, so it can be parsed as a number correctly.

Comment: I tried string replace, but doing that is removing my image url too... so cannot really use string replace.

Comment: What is the value of `$desc`? I assumed it was `$235.99`. How would removing the dollar sign from that affect an image URL?

Comment: the image url has $_35 http://i2.wp.com/i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEwMFgxMTAw/z/7~UAAOSwu4BV0l0F/$_35.JPG?fit=518%2C190

Comment: What does that have to do with this question? You just want to display the price, the image shouldn't be in that. The second argument to `money_format` is just a number.